# GooglePlacesAutocomplete styling on the list content of results react-native

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I have a trouble to style the list result area of GooglePlacesAutocomplete.
Can anyone help how to style result row with full background colour and border radius of result container?

[image: Problem]

I would like the row with background colour without this margin.

Here is my code:

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder={'MY PLACEHOLDER'}
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              myOnPressCode
            }}
            query={{
              myQuery
            }}
            textInputProps={{
              placeholderTextColor: colors.searchModalPlaceHolderColor,
            }}
            fetchDetails={true}
            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
            styles={{
              container: {
                alignSelf: 'stretch',
                borderRadius: 16,
              },
              textInput: {
                height: 46,
                color: colors.text,
                borderRadius: 16,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: colors.primary,
                backgroundColor: colors.searchModalInputBackground,
                fontSize: 18,
                paddingHorizontal: 15,
              },
            }}
            renderRow={(rowData) => {
              const title = rowData.structured_formatting.main_text;
              const address = rowData.structured_formatting.secondary_text;
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: '100%',
                  }}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}>{title}</Text>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}>{address}</Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

For row background colour:

```
row: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      paddingVertical: 0,
      paddingHorizontal: 0,
    },

containerResultRow: {
      flex: 1,
      height: 55,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingHorizontal: 15,
      backgroundColor:
        rowIndex && (rowIndex + 1) % 2 === 0
          ? 'blue'
          : 'gray',
    },
```

For listView borderRadius:

https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/issues/792